# Is it possible to run replication on a SQL 2005 DB which is a mirrored principal server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, replication, mirroring

We have a client that currently has a large busy database that they back up using database mirroring.  As part of a reporting requirement we need to use some of the data stored in the database to run reports against but we cannot access the data directly.

Is it possible for us to run transaction replication on that server to get our data while it is running database mirroring at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to run transaction log shipping at the same time you are running mirroring. It is also possible to bring the secondary server up in a "Read Only" mode rather than "Standby" for the specific purpose of allowing you to run reports on the second server.